# How to create warning message in trigger?

Tags: triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

Is it possible to create a warning message in a trigger in Firebird 2.5?

I know I can create an exception message which will stop the user from saving the record changes, but in this instance I don't mind if the user continues.

Could I call a procedure that generates the message?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with _"but in this instance I don't mind if the user continues."_. See also the discussion in the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in Firebird to produce warnings in PSQL code, you can only raise exceptions, which in triggers will result in the effect of the executed statement that fired the trigger to be undone.

In short, this is not possible.

There are workarounds possible, but those would require 'external' protocols, like, for example, inserting the warning message into a global temporary table, requiring the calling code to explicitly select from that temporary table after execution.

Comment: There is no workaround like that possible, because there ain't such thing a "after execution". Read the middle of the question evaluating it as "user story", he wants literally a confirmation modal dialog, that would put data writing sequance on pause and then wait from extra data from client to either fault and rollback or continue and commit. No such thing in standard SQL is possible. Query is either executed or not. Well, okay, UDF voodoo can do if abomination enough, but better not.

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't see where you get the idea the OP wants a confirmation dialog, they never mention anything like that at all. The middle of the question you're referring to is what the OP **doesn't want** (an exception that stops execution).

Comment: "but in this instance I don't mind if the user continues" - what is your interpretation of "user continues" and why/how TS can chose to "mind" or "not mind" this "continuation by user"? To me it is unconditional abort vs conditional continuation after a confirmation pause. OK, TS will probably say tomorrow if i read too much into it, maybe i did.

Comment: Can an exception be used by more than one trigger? Is there a general exception that can be used by any trigger? 
About 18 months ago, I created an exception for a trigger which works fine. Now, the exception looks more like an error. So the trigger still compiles and the exception still halts the trigger, but it looks ugly. It says:
Exception 243
USRDEF_NOSUPPLIERINALS
Supplier Required in Line Source Tab.
At trigger 'USRDEF_UPDATECOSTPRICE' line: 1 col 3606.

I would expect just:
Supplier Required in Line Source Tab.

Comment: @SimonKing That sounds like something unrelated to this question, which would warrant posting a separate questions. However, exceptions in Firebird are objects just like tables, triggers etc, and they are not restricted to a single trigger.

Comment: @Arioch'The I interpreted that as that the code shouldn't halt, just issue a warning, but you're right, the way it is phrased could be interpreted otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

SQL model does provide putting query on pause and then waiting for extra input from client to either unfreeze it or fail it. SQL is not user-interactive service and there is no confirmation dialogs. You have to rethink your application design.

---

One possible avenue, nominally staying withing 2-tier client-server framework, would be creating temporary tabless for all the data you want to save (for example transaction-scope GTTs), and then have TWO stored procedures. One SP would be sanity-checking and returning list of warnings, if any. Another SP then would dump the data from GTTs to main, persistent tables without doing those checks.

Your client app would `select` warnings from the check-SP first, if it returns any then show them to the user, then either call save-SP and commit, or rollback without calling save-SP.

This is abusing C/S idea, so there would be dragons. First of all, you would have to have several GTTs and two SPs for E-V-E-R-Y pausable data saving in your app. And that can be a lot.

Also, notice, that database data **may change** after you called check-SP and before you called save-SP. Becuse some OTHER application running elsewhere could be changing and committing data during that pause. Especially if you transaction was of `READ COMMMITTED` kind. But with `SNAPSHOT` tx too.

---

Better approach would be to drop C/S scheme and go to 3-tier model, AKA multi-tier, AKA "Application Server". That way your client app sends the "briefcase" of data to the app-server, it would be app-server (not SQL triggers) doing all the data validation, and then it would be saving it to data storage backend, SQL or any other.

There, of course, still would be that problem, that data could had been changed by other users, why you paused one user and waited him to read and decide. But you would have more flexibility in app-server on data reconcilation, than you would have with plain SQL.